# Making a bottle brick wall using geonodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

We will be building a bottle brick wall in our community, and I'm battling Youtube tutorials and geometry nodes trying to figure out how to model it. After a couple of hours, it is time to ask for help!

[image: Bottle Brick wall example]

We will make physical bottle bricks by cutting two similar bottles in half and then taping them together to make a cylinder. The final physical build will introduce some variation in positioning, and bottle bricks will also vary a bit in diameter. But for now I want something simple that works.

So that keeps modelling simple. We just need to do a grid of 3cm radius cylinders, 20cm long cutting a wall (5.5m long, 2.0m high, 20cm thick), with the grid spacing at 10cm (grid 55x20)

And then colour those bottle bricks according to a simple image of the same resolution (55x20).

Comment: As I look at the image, I realise a hex grid would be better. So bonus points for that?
Community members will be painting up a page each for selecting the final design, so hex grids will work for that too.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't use your measurements, but I made it so that you could change the number and dimensions. You can get more variations in diameter of the bottles with a collection.

I downloaded a wine bottle from blender kit to simplify the modelling task.

If you are trying to create a hex grid wall with circular shapes in it, `duplicate elements` is a key node here. This has one material that allows you to randomize all the colours.:

[image]

The materials are like this:

[image]

My finished result, essentially:

[image]

edit: If you wish to limit the numbers of colors with a ColorRamp node, it will work like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks great. I went back to my safe space and "faked" it which looks ok for a first pass. 
I'll give this a crack tomorrow. Rather than random colour, it will be picking up colour from an actual image (selected from those drawn by community members).

Any tips on how to tie the material colour for each bottle to an image? 
There are only like 6 or 8 colours in total (mostly shades of green and brown, plus "flint" and blue)

Comment: My bet is that you can find a solution with putting your 8 custom colours on a color ramp.